# Как получить прогресс считывания строк из файла?

Tags: c#, progress-bar

Нужно показывать прогресс выполнения вот этой строчки кода через компонент *progressBar1*

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(name, Encoding.Default));
```

Comment: `ReadAllLines` не оповещает о прогрессе, да и работать должно быстро, если вы не грузите файл очень большого размера.

Comment: Так дело в том, что это текстовый файл очень большого размера.
Тогда скажите пожалуйста, какой процедурой или функцией воспользоваться, чтобы она оповещала о прогрессе?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, если файл реально очень большой, я бы не советовал грузить его в `ListBox`. Кроме того, чтение всего файла происходит целиком, и не даёт вам асинхронности, так что надо делить чтение на куски.

Вам придётся сделать вашу процедуру асинхронной, чтобы окно не подвисало:

```
var batchSize = 100; // найдите хорошее значение экспериментально
using (var r = File.OpenText(path))
{
    while (true)
    {
        var batch = await GetBatch(r, batchSize);
        if (batch == null)
            break;
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(batch);
        // тут обновите прогресс
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}
```

Вспомогательная функция:

```
async Task<string[]> GetBatch(StreamReader r, int batchSize)
{
    var batch = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
    {
        var line = await r.ReadLineAsync();
        if (line == null)
            break;
        batch.Add(line);
    }
    if (batch.Count == 0)
        return null;
    return batch.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно грузить файл построчно. Тогда ты будешь видеть некий прогресс, но что бы знать сколько осталось, нужно знать общее кол-во строк.

Что бы получить кол-во строк, можно вспользоваться вот этим: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119559/determine-the-number-of-lines-within-a-text-file

Я думаю, что это должно быстро отработать даже на большом файле.

Если все таки считывание кол-ва строк-это долгий процесс, то можно начать считывать строки в одном потоке, предварительно не зная кол-во строк в файле (В прогресс баре писать считана 1 строка из  N), а в другом потоке запустить подсчет кол-ва строк. Когда ты узнаешь кол-во строк, обновить прогресс бар (Добавить всего кол-во строк, например считана 1 строка из 10000).